# How to take a snapshot of a chart and save into Byte Array in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I'm trying to capture snapshot of a chart and save that image as a Byte Array in flex.  currently i'm using this method to save a snapshot but now i want to save image in a Byte array. Is this possible ?

this is my current method

```
       private function takeSnapshot():void{
        var image:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(chart);
        var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
        var fileName:String = "chart.png";
        file.save(image.data,fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do in AS3:

```
// displayObject being the object to render
var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(displayObject.width, displayObject.height, true, 0);
data.draw(displayObject);
// the you can have either a raw bytearray or a png:
var bitmapBa:ByteArray = data.getPixels( new Rectangle(0, 0, displayObject.width, displayObject.height);
// or if you're saving to PNG:
var pngBA:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode( data );
```